# php project working on windows but not on linux

Tags: php, linux, netbeans, centos, virtualbox

I'm trying to run a php project on linux with virtual box and Cent OS server , but not the whole page is echoing !!
The project is working on windows with wamp server successfully ! 
I faced same issues before and it was a privileges problem ,
These two command lines were helpful :

```
chmod -R a+rw *
chown -R apche:apache *
```

but this time it's not working and it's driving me crazy !!
what's the problem ?

Comment: Have you looked at your server's error logs? Do you have PHP error reporting enabled (a recommended development/debugging value is -1)?

Comment: see your error_logs + check that paths you use (for example to include), note windows `c:\smth\smth\file;` linux `/smt/smt/file;` . i suggest make a homogeneous (in OS installation and settings  and hardware) development environment, especially the server part.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant for paths in your application? Because in Linux the path separator is `/`, in Windows, it is either `\` or `/` and it might broke you application.